# a href in FT InfoWindow not working as I would like

Tags: html, hyperlink, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

Here is my code for the infowindow:

```
<div class='googft-info-window' align='center' style='font-family: sans-serif'>
<b>{CLIENT NAME}</b> <br>
<i>{CITY}</i><p>
<font color="red"><b>BONUS: </b>{BONUS}</font color> <br>
<a href="{WEBSITE}"><i>Learn More</i></a></div>
```

When user clicks Learn More, I would like this to open another page with further information. Instead, what is actually happening is the link is being followed, within the map frame.

I would like the link to take user to another page on the site.
I think this thread
[Inserting a rails link into a Google Maps infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031832/inserting-a-rails-link-into-a-google-maps-infowindow)
answers my question, but I don't really understand all the additional code.

I am VERY new to FT and appreciate all the knowledge here.

Thanks in advance,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

With valid (X)HTML as far as I know there is no way to determine in- or out-of-frame links. How ever if you're willing to drop validity you can use the anchor target attribute set to `"_top"`

Or if you want you can use Javascript `window.top.location`; but that will end up causing unwanted behavior for those without Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can say this:

`<a href="{WEBSITE}" target="_blank">Learn More</a>`